# VScode notebooks dont update to the latest code

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Im working on a data science project which involves a lot of visualisation as a result of a large python package. Therefore I have a large collection of .py files and one resultant .ipynb file which calls the rest of the Python files.

For example:

**notebook.ipynb**
import x from y
import y from z
Do x

Where x and y are the .py files.

If I run this on a normal jupyter notebook it runs fine and will use the latest code - after I push it to github from vscode and then pull the latest version within Jupyter.

However, when I do the same within the VScode notebooks the code never seems to update. It will always run a past version even if the code has been pushed, pulled.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: show definitive evidence that the pull has succeeded and that the working tree is at the commit you want without any unstaged changes.

Comment: The pull has definitely succeeded as I can run the updates in a completely seperate Jupyter environment which pulls from GitHub.

Comment: It shouldn’t even require it to be pulled as the file is in the same directory as the .py files and it pulls from there and not GitHub.